# Is this sort of an audio adapter splitter that I'm looking for?

Tags: audio, microphone, splitter

I have [ASUS N550JV](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JV/specifications/) laptop and it has one COMBO audio jack. I want to use my [Logitech G230](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g230-stereo-gaming-headset) audio headset which has two jacks, one for audio and one for microphone.

Searching the web, I realized I need an audio adapter splitter like the one below.

[image]

---

So I went through my old pile of cables and old hardware and found something which looks to me something similar to what I need.

[image]
[image]

*(There are no icons or text anywhere on the device that specifies what type of input goes where, unlike the colored splitter above)*

I tried plugging in this device and connecting my headphones to it but I had no sound on my headphones.

So, is this the splitter that I'm looking for or do I have a software issue that I need to fix tweaking some options through Windows?

Comment: This looks like an audio splitter only (two headphone sockets from one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you pulled out of your cable pile is NOT what you need. That thing appears to have two [RCA jacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) on it, not headphone jacks. Plugging your headphones into them will do nothing, as they are a different type of connector altogether, and only have one conductor in the center.

Further you'll notice that the picture you got from the web shows the male connector having 4 conductive regions, while your adapter has only 3, further re-enforcing the idea that it's the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

No, the jack you've pictured is a 3.5mm to RCA adapter and not at all what you want.

You should go to your local Radio Shack or equivalent and look for one of these (or just buy this one):

*StarTech.com Headset adapter for headsets with separate headphone / microphone plugs - 3.5mm 4 position to 2x 3 position 3.5mm M/F*

http://smile.amazon.com/StarTech-com-headsets-separate-headphone-microphone/dp/B004SP0WAQ

I believe the combo connector is called a 4 position 3.5mm jack, and you'll want it to break out to 2 3-position 3.5mm jacks.