# Do all splitters work for headset + mic?

Tags: audio, speakers, microphone

I have a headset with a mic on it, and two different cables, green for audio, pink for mic. However in my laptop there is only a single audio socket, so I think I have to use a splitter. But I wonder if any splitter will work for this. For example this one looks like it is for using two speakers (not mic + speaker) , but I hope I am wrong.

So will this work for me? : http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/headphone-splitter-35mm-cogaltici.html#galeri

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/850497/is-this-sort-of-an-audio-adapter-splitter-that-im-looking-for

Comment: Your link won't load for me, but no a "splitter" is not what you want at all, you need this: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B004SP0WAQ/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1451405603&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=headset+adapter&dpPl=1&dpID=41WCy3b0sCL&ref=plSrch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suspect right that the stereo splitter you've linked will not work.

In your case you don't want a "splitter", you want a "joiner".

Dual 3-ring to single 4-ring: ie: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004SP0WAQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SP0WAQ)

[image]

Comment: thanks, so i will search for a joiner. and how can i understand when i see one? do they always have the speaker and mic icons on them?

Comment: Splitters will have 2 visible rings on the tip, joiners will have 3. In the case of this answer, the 3 black rings around the tip. 

A little late to help at the time, but hopefully can help others in the future.